# Irreversible encrypted password in HPE LoadRunner

Tags: testing, loadrunner

I have been running some performance test on one of my websites and I have been trying to encrypt my password for safety reasons. Every method I have tried is easily reversible if someone has access to my scripts. Does anyone know how to do this properly? LoadRunner documentation is quite poor. I have tried

Using parameters: (actual password can be seen in paramaters)

```
"Name=Username", "Value={Username}", ENDITEM, 
"Name=Password", "Value={Password}", ENDITEM,
```

Using masked strings, can be also reversible.

```
"Name=Username", lr_unmask("5c5c433589e471556dd55bdac0336170f7c36ea3b32869fec2ee1ffa15"), ENDITEM,
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Its MicroFocus LoadRunner now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a public encryption algorithm.  Supply the decryption key for the data as part of a run time parameter (see run time settings for parameters).  Encrypt your parameter data with the key in question.  This way you can store your data encrypted, using a key which is only known by you before execution.

[image]

Comment: Note that this value will be stored as plain text in default.cfg

Comment: I would leave it blank when I save, or provide a false value.  Update in the controller.  Yes, there is a risk that this would be stored in the .lrs file, but then encryption is only there to provide a barrier to the information.  No barrier is perfect, just good enough to prevent almost all curious.

Comment: In TruWeb we have a genuine encryption capability where the password is stored in an external location of your choosing and the input/output is sanitized to not include the decrypted values.

Answer (score 0):

WebHttp protocol doesn't have an encryption feature. For encryption you can use the TruWeb protocol (https://admhelp.microfocus.com/truweb/en/latest/help/Content/TruWeb/TW-masking.htm) or implement your own way to use an encryption algorithm.

EDIT: Alternatively you can store values in VTS -
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.60-12.61/help/WebHelp/Content/VTS/c_getting-started.htm